# Why snipcart digital goods verification fails

Tags: checkout, verification, snipcart

I’ve been stuck on this for a while now.
I’m trying to set up a digital products webshop, using Vue + Strapi + Snipcart.

Here’s the error I’m encountering once I try to checkout with a product:
[browser error message from snipcart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I5Zz.png)

However, If I test with a normal product that doesn’t have guid attached to it - everything is fine and the transaction goes through.
I use snipcart’s JSON crawler. Therefore I’ve created an endpoint from my API with all products.

```
JSON structure
{ 
"_id":"618ff1327f4e2824f09134cf",
"price":123,
"file_guid":"7571fd60-a403-404c-b27a-616c0856e1ee",
"id":"618ff1327f4e2824f09134cf"
}
...
```

The only thing that comes to my mind - is that I’m not correctly referencing guid in my JSON document
I’ve also tried just `guid` instead `file_guid` - it didn’t work.

Lastly this is my “Add to cart” button code:

```
<v-btn dark depressed class="mt-5 snipcart-add-item"
  :data-item-id="productDetails.id"
  :data-item-description="productDetails.shortDescription"
  :data-item-price="productDetails.price"
  :data-item-image="apiUrl + productDetails.image.url"
  :data-item-name="productDetails.title"
  :data-item-url="'https://92ef-91-101-56-233.ngrok.io/products/snipcart'"
  :data-item-max-quantity="1"
  :data-item-min-quantity="1"
  :data-item-file-guid="productDetails.file_guid"
  >ADD TO CART</v-btn>
```

Everything is running and tested locally using ngrok.
Does anyone have any ideas of what I’m doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve managet to figure out the issue. As I suspected I was referencing `guid` wrong (`file_guid` and `guid`), that’s why snipcart’s JSON crawler was returning me the error.
I’ve found in some random repository that **You must use the name** `fileGuid` in your API otherwise crawler won’t find it.